# Json Serialize/Deserialize to retain the type of property object within a class

Tags: c#, json

I don't have much Json serialization/deserialization, but this has become a real issue and I can't help feeling that I'm missing something...

When I serialize an object, which has an object as a property, the object type isn't retained and therefore when deserialized isn't the correct object type. How do I ensure that the correct object type property is serialized/deserialized?

Example object to Json:

```
public class InfoPoint
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public object? Value { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Program to show the issue:

```
List<InfoPoint> infoPoints = new List<InfoPoint>();

InfoPoint infoPoint1 = new InfoPoint();
infoPoint1.Name = "Point1";
bool status = true;
infoPoint1.Value = status;
infoPoint1.Location = "Main Switch Status";
infoPoints.Add(infoPoint1);

InfoPoint infoPoint2 = new InfoPoint();
infoPoint2.Name = "Point2";
UInt16 volume = 75;
infoPoint2.Value = volume;
infoPoint2.Location = "Volume Dial";
infoPoints.Add(infoPoint2);

InfoPoint infoPoint3 = new InfoPoint();
infoPoint3.Name = "Point3";
float[] sliders = new float[] { 2.3f, 1.79f, 8.77f, 5.5f };
infoPoint3.Value = sliders;
infoPoint3.Location = "Fader Panel";
infoPoints.Add(infoPoint3);

JsonSerializerSettings settings
    = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoPoint1, settings));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoPoint2, settings));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoPoint3, settings));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoPoints, settings));
```

Then the ouput:

```
{
  "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
  "Name": "Point1",
  "Value": true,
  "Location": "Main Switch Status"
}
{
  "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
  "Name": "Point2",
  "Value": 75,
  "Location": "Volume Dial"
}
{
  "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
  "Name": "Point3",
  "Value": {
    "$type": "System.Single[], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "$values": [
      2.3,
      1.79,
      8.77,
      5.5
    ]
  },
  "Location": "Fader Panel"
}
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest]], System.Private.CoreLib",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
      "Name": "Point1",
      "Value": true,
      "Location": "Main Switch Status"
    },
    {
      "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
      "Name": "Point2",
      "Value": 75,
      "Location": "Volume Dial"
    },
    {
      "$type": "JsonObjectListTest.InfoPoint, JsonObjectListTest",
      "Name": "Point3",
      "Value": {
        "$type": "System.Single[], System.Private.CoreLib",
        "$values": [
          2.3,
          1.79,
          8.77,
          5.5
        ]
      },
      "Location": "Fader Panel"
    }
  ]
}
```

Point2 holds an object of type UInt16, I need it to retain that type when deserialized. I've done a lot of research, but how do I serialize and deserialize to retain the resulting property as a UInt16. It's vital that the object type of property "Value" is correct.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Do you really, really need to define `Value` property as `object?`? Have you considered using generics instead?

Comment: Yes, I have considered using generics, as the third party API I'm using also uses generics. But even then if I don't pass back to the API the "Value" as the correct type it throws a spanner, so I have to keep the object type. I would also say that how do you deserialize into the correct generic type if you don't know that type?

Comment: You may be able to do this with a class hierarchy with `BaseInfoPoint` at its root, including a _NotSerialized_ virtual `Value` property, and then a group of subclasses (`BoolInfoPoint`, `ShortInfoPoint`, `FloatArrayInfoPoint`), each having an appropriately typed `RawValue`, and code to covert between the raw value and the actual `Value`. Then use polymorphic serialization & deserialization to wrap it all up. Not simple, bit it should work (but your serialized format will need to include type info (at the object level, not the property level).

Comment: @Flydog57 I thought something like this was going to be the way suggested, which does feel overly complicated. I did want to use generics (as suggested by @Rui-Jarimba), but  I also don't understand how you then serialize/deserialize a generic class... any pointers on that also welcome!